# Handle sync data updates between Server and Device

Tags: android, api, synchronization, updates

My team and I are struggling to find a solution on how to handle properly synchronization between data on the user's device (Android), and data on the server.  The situation is the following:

User logs in in their device, which will make a request to a REST API and return a list of contents on the server.  This will then be saved locally on the device.

This list may change from time to time, and I need to keep it updated on the device. I use a Scheduler Job with a 1-day period, which will download this list again.

The problem is that we don't want to download it all the time since it'll increases user's data traffic.  We only want to download it when there's an update in this list data.

We are trying to use some kind of checksum, and then return a 304 error when there's no update available.  However, we are not entirely sure how to make it work correctly.

The same user can log in an Android device, or desktop, and the 'first time' he logs in, server must return a 200, and obtain the list.

After that, only return a 200 if there's an update.  We don't know exactly how we should solve this.

I don't know if I made myself clear, it's kinda hard to explain. It's basically a synchronization between server only when there's an update available.

Comment: This is a very broad question and isn't really suitable for SO.  However, what you're looking to do is pretty simple to configure if you're the one that's writing the backend RESTful API.  Just match the hash if a client passed one and return the response/body as needed.  Just be aware that hashing can be an "expensive" operation in some cases and may require a lot of compute power.

Comment: This sounds very similar to what I wanted a few months ago. Overall, the topic is much more complicated than it seems. However, there is a strategy that uses a built-in feature with HTTP called Entity Tags (ETags). If both sides support it, the result is a technique knowing the data needs to be updated. Please read http://www.apiacademy.co/how-to-http-caching-for-restful-hypermedia-apis/ This did not seem like a full answer but it should be enough to get started.